# AttributeError: module 'semver' has no attribute 'compare' [Python-Gitlab]

Tags: python, python-3.x, semantic-versioning

I'm getting this error in vscode.

> AttributeError: module 'semver' has no attribute 'compare'

1. Python version: Python 3.10.6
2. Pip version: pip 22.3
3. semver version: 2.8.1

```
    import semver
    
    def is_equals():
        result = semver.compare('0.0.1', '1.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your filename. Gives error if "semver" is same as filename

Rename your python filename
And
pip install semver